# Spline IK modifie by a Curve modifier with involuntary rotation

Tags: bones, bezier-curves

I'm new with Blender and I love it :)

But I have some problems with « SplineIK » and « Curve modifier ».

I need to animate many fish swimming in a circle and import it in Unity 3D.

So I want an animation with bones follows a curve circle with zigzag.

[image: Animation without bones]

I almost succeed with a « SpineIK » on my bones, which get modified by a « Curve modifier ».
This method works, but I get some rotation issues.

[image]

As you can see, it's looking like the bones lean into turns. The effect can be cool, but not in my case ^^ 
I need to have a full control of the rotation.

I've tried using the Tilt of the curve, but it doesn't affect my bones.

I've tried using Limit Rotation and nothing change except when I choose « Local Space » in « Convert » the rotation begin at the start of my Circle.
When it's « World Space » the rotation appears in the middle of the circle and disappear at the start…

Any ideas to keep the control of the rotation are welcome :)

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use a curve modified mesh, a string of verts and tangent verts individually grouped, to create points for pseudo-spline IK bones to track and "see" tilt, if that would get you want you want.  Spline IK screws up or overrides other constraints on the same bones, so for constraints, you want coincident children, after which you could use locked track to hold their roll.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I don't understand "coincident children" I really don't understand what happen. Why the bone bends into the curve?... I've tried the constraint "Child of" and the rotation happen in the middle of the curve. Without it's at the start and the end. And the contraints "Locked track" change the rotation but don't hold it.